# Is there an object browser for the built-in or custom objects?

Tags: custom-object, sobject

Being a noob, it's difficult to get my head wrapped around the vastness of the salesforce expanse.

In Visual Studio and other environments like the standard Java Eclipse, they typically have an object browser where you can inspect the properties, methods, events, enums, etc... of all the objects in the framework.

Is there such a thing in the Salesforce world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Schema Builder is through the UI. If you would like to browse SObjects through Eclipse, you can use the [Schema Explorer](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_IDE), which is available whenever you add a Force.com nature to a project.

Comment: Just open the "salesforce.schema" file in the Force.com IDE to get to the Schema Explorer, and have an interface for testing SOQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called the Schema Builder. In the old setup menu it's under App Setup (I'm not sure where it is in the new interface; probably under Develop.) It's an interactive ER diagram that also allows you to modify your schema.

See the [Schema Builder Overview](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=schema_builder.htm) for more information.

Comment: I don't see objects such as ProcessInstance.  Where can I see those?

Comment: It doesn't have every object. You'll have to look through the documentation and help files. Example for ProcessInstance - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm